# ElasticSearch Logstash JDBC: How to aggregate into different column names

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I am new to Elasticsearch and I am trying to use Logstash to load data to an index. Following is a partial of my losgstash config:

```
filter {
  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{code}"
    code => "
      map['campaignId'] = event.get('CAM_ID')
      map['country'] = event.get('COUNTRY')
      map['countryName'] = event.get('COUNTRYNAME')
    # etc
    "
    push_previous_map_as_event => true
    timeout => 5
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    document_id => "%{code}"
    document_type => "company"
    index => "company_v1"
    codec => "json"
    hosts => ["127.0.0.1:9200"]
  }
}
```

I was expecting that the aggregation would map for instance the column 'CAM_ID' into a property in the ElasticSearch Index as 'campaignId'. Instead, is creating a property with the name 'cam_id' which is the column name as lowercase. The same with the rest of the properties.

Following is the Index Document after logstash being executed:

```
{
  "company_v1": {
    "aliases": {

    },
    "mappings": {
      "company": {
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "@version": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "cam_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "campaignId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "cam_type": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "campaignType": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1545905435871",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "Dz0x16ohQWWpuhtCB3Y4Vw",
        "version": {
          "created": "6050399"
        },
        "provided_name": "company_v1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

'campaignId' and 'campaignType' were created by me when i created the index, but logstash created the other 2.

Can someone explain me how to configure logstash to customize the indexes documents properties names when data is being loaded?

Thank you very much.

Best Regards